Derivative of a gradient flow $T(x)=\exp_x(\nabla\psi(x))$
Consider a gradient flow
$$T(x)=\exp_x(\nabla\psi(x))$$
on a Riemannian manifold $M$, with $\psi\in C^\infty(M)$. What is the derivative of this flow?
I mean, if $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$, who is
$$dT_p(X_p)=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}T(\gamma(t))=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}\exp_{\gamma(t)}(\nabla\psi(\gamma(t)))?$$
Do I get a Hamilton-Jacobi equation?
